# When i attempt to sign up and i know that all the post things work, it says user could not e created

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli("192.99.56.236", "root", "fakepass", "thesucc");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//two passwords maching
if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {

    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']); //md5 is hash
    $avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

    //make sure fike is image
    if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {
        //copy image to images folder
        if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)) {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, avatar) "
                . "VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$avatar_path')";

            //if the query success, redirect to welcome.php, done!
            if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration succesfull! Added $username to the database!";
                header("location: welcome.php");
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be created!";
            }

        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "File upload failed!";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Please only upload image files!";
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords do not match!";
}
}

?>
```

this is my code, the mysql info is changed but i know i had it correct i checked over many a time. i have looked through a lot and i cannot seem to figure out what the problem is but i think ive narrowed it down to something to do with the variables not being able to post into mysql

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: More than likely has something to do with your connection (it getting denied etc). Put the following after your connection to determine the error (if there is one): `if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);`

Comment: Your code is failing on way too many levels and there are a few unknowns that also stand to be failing. Best you start checking for errors via php's error reporting and on the query.

Answer (score -3):

Change this line:

```
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
```

To this:

```
if ($mysqli->query($sql) )
```

Comment: if youd like to see for yourself here is a link https://thesucc.000webhostapp.com/form.php